# Mandar NULL al campo de la BD

Tags: php, mysql

estoy haciendo un ejercicio con PHP y MySQL donde hago un formulario con una serie de datos. El campo teléfono permite nulo, asique el usuario lo deja en blanco en la base de dato quiero que se guarde como *NULL* pero se me quede un hueco en blanco.

Imagen de la BD:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código PHP:

```
<?php
    $correo = $_POST["correo"];
    $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    if(isset($_POST["telefono"]))   
        $telefono = $_POST["telefono"];      
    else
        $telefono = NULL;

    if(isset($_POST["publicidad"]))
        $publicidad = 1;     
    else
        $publicidad = 0;            

    $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bdusuarios");//Conexion BD

    $consulta = "INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES(DEFAULT,'".$correo."','".$nombre."','".$password."',DEFAULT,".$publicidad.",'".$telefono."');";//ConsultaSQL

    $consulta_correo = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE correo = '".$correo."'"; //Consulta para comprobar el correo

    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta_correo);//Comprobacion del correo

    if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado) == 0)//Si la consulta del correo es 0, es porque no existe ese correo en la BD y se puede registrar
    {
        if(mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta))//Si la consulta es correcta...
        {
            echo "<h3>Usuario registrado correctamente</h3>";
            echo "Filas afectadas: ".mysqli_affected_rows($conexion);;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Error al registrar el usuario";
        }
    }
    else////Si la consulta del correo es distinto de 0, es porque ya hay un usuario con ese correo
    {
        echo "<h3>Ya existe un usuario con ese correo</h3>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Intenta poner `"null"` como cadena en vez de solo `NULL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En primer lugar **tienes que verificar que esa columna admita valores `NULL`**, de lo contrario el código fallará.

En segundo lugar, la forma correcta de introducir valores nulos, es introduciendo esto `NULL` y no esto `'NULL'`.

Si tú escribes:

```
INSERT INTO usuarios (telefono) VALUES ('NULL');
```

Lo que harás será introducir **una cadena que dice NULL** en la columna.

En cambio, si escribes:

```
INSERT INTO usuarios (telefono) VALUES (NULL);
```

Estarás introduciendo realmente un valor `NULL` en la columna.

Finalmente, para un futuro, considera asegurar tus consultas contra la Inyección SQL usando consultas preparadas.

Answer (score 2):

tu problema es al armar la consulta

```
$consulta = "INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES(DEFAULT,'".$correo."','".$nombre."','".$password."',DEFAULT,".$publicidad.",'".$telefono."');";//ConsultaSQL
```

como puedes observar le estas colocando comillas al valor asi sea vacio `'".$telefono."'`
una solucion es

```
$telefono = trim($_POST["telefono"] != "") ? "'".$_POST["telefono"]."'" : NULL;
```

y en la consulta

```
$consulta = "INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES(DEFAULT,'".$correo."','".$nombre."','".$password."',DEFAULT,".$publicidad."","
.$telefono.")";
```

PHP coloco las obsolteas las librerias `mysql` te recomiendo leer mas sobre 
 [SQL Inyection](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/28035)

Answer (score 2):

Si envias las cadenas vacias a la instruccion, se guardara la cadena vacia para guardar el valor por defecto puedes omitir el valor cambiando tu sintaxis y especificando los campos que deseas guardar.

para tu ejemplo puedes validar el valor de la cadena antes de enviarla.

```
$correo = !empty($correo) ? "'" . $correo . "'" : 'null';
$nombre = !empty($nombre) ? "'" . $nombre . "'" : 'null';
$password = !empty($password) ? "'" . $password . "'" : 'null';
$telefono = !empty($telefono) ? "'" . $telefono . "'" : 'null';
$consulta = "INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES(null,".$correo.",".$nombre.",".$password.",null,".$publicidad.","
.$telefono.")";
```

Answer (score 1):

Buenas,

Ten en cuenta que la query es un string.

Por tanto, deberías usar:

```
if(isset($_POST["telefono"]))   
    $telefono = $_POST["telefono"];      
else
    $telefono = "NULL";
```

Comment: Que va amigo, lo he puesto así como dices pero lo sigue dejando en blanco

Answer (score 1):

Existe la función `NULLIF()` en MySQL, recibe dos parámetros y si ambos coinciden la función devuelve `NULL` de lo contrario imprime el primer parámetro tal cual llegó.
Por ejemplo:

```
"INSERT INTO frutas SET nombre = NULLIF($nombre,'');"
```

Si el campo Nombre estaba vacio, la variable `$nombre` va a contener un string vacío, tal cual especificamos que espere la función `NULLIF`, por lo que va a insertar en la base de datos un `NULL`, pero si habia escrito Manzana inserta Manzana.